# How To have UITableView Resize when only 1 row

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autosize

I have a `UITableView` with a border that has a prototype cell with multi-line labels in it.  The table may only have one row in it depending on the data.  Everything about the cell itself seems to work fine.

The challenge is that my border goes well beyond the data when there are not enough rows of data to fill up table.  I do have a bottom constraint on the `Table View` and this I know why it is bigger than the single row.

What I can't figure out is how to change my constraints on the table view so that it is only as big as the data being display.

Below is a screen shot of what I am getting.  What I want is for the border to be only around the row of data that is displayed.  Of course if the table has multiple rows that make it larger than the available space at the bottom of the page where it is located, I do need it to scroll etc.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

And yes I have confirmed that the cell is not taking up the entire width by turning on the row separators and verifying more than `1` show.  I have also confirmed that the number of sections in the table view is set to `1` and that a value of `1` is being returned in the `numberOfRowsInSection` function.

[image]

Comment: what you return at method: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: This is swift code and I do not implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of 3 solutions for your situation. The first one is to manually pre-calculate the size of your table view like `Min(yourAvailableHeight, heightOfRow*numberOfRows + topMargin + bottomMargin)`. Or you can remove the bottom border itself and only put it in the last cell.

Or you can use

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: So - first I am 99% sure the three lines of code could be condensed into one as follows:  tblPlaceEvents.frame.size.height = tblPlaceEvents.contentSize.height.  Regardless it does not work as the the height is listed by the application as 44 - which is too small and causes the data to be cut off.  This result also appears to invalidate any solution that would use the rowHeigh as it does not seem to give the correct value.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: So this answer actually did work once I fixed my auto layout / autosizing issues in the table.  By that I mean left top right and bottom constraints on all the labels in the prototypecell as well as these two lines of code in the viewDidLoad method:         tblPlaceEvents.estimatedRowHeight = 87
        tblPlaceEvents.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.  Then I could put this one line of code in the viewDidAppear function and it worked. tblPlaceEvents.frame.size.height = tblPlaceEvents.contentSize.height  tblPlaceEvents is the outlet name for my tableView.

Comment: One more thing - for this to work correctly, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function I needed to have the following line of code lobj_EventEntry!.layoutIfNeeded() where lob_EventEntry is the cell I am going to return from the function.